# bakcup files using rsync without copying files which decreased in size

Tags: ubuntu, backup, rsync

I have a directory in my server which contains some media files. Files will be add to the directory time to time, but after a file added to this directory it won't change ever. I want to backup this directory using rsync. The problem is in a hard failure some of these files' size became zero and my rsync command copied the corrupted files in backup directory and ruined my backup. I want to not copy files which decreased in size. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use find to clean up all the files with size zero

```
cd /path/to/dir;find -size 0b | xargs rm -rf
```

then rerun rsync

- Test this command on a subset of files to verify before running it on your real data